# How can I render circles around rectangle in Konva js?

Tags: javascript, konvajs, react-konva

I need to render table and chairs like in this picture:

[image]

I dont know how to calculate position of circles around rect. I tried some code, but its not working...Anybody knows how to solve it?

Check my code:

```
 let smallCircleRadius = 20
let tableSize = { 
    width: ((seats-4/2)*(smallCircleRadius)),
    height: ((seats-4/2)*(smallCircleRadius))
}
let controlY = 0
let totalCircleSide = (seats-4)/2
let controlX = 0
let distanceY = 0
let distanceX = 0
let table = new Konva.Rect({
    width: tableSize.width,
    height: tableSize.height,
    fill: '#fff',
    stroke: '#c3c6cf',//'#b2cfcf',
    strokeWidth: 8,
    x:150,
    y: 150
});
let count = 0

group.add(table)


for (var i = 0; i < seats; i++) {
    

    // let distanceToTable =  tableSize.width/2;
    // let x = i <= 2 ? table.x() + distanceToTable * i + (smallCircleRadius + 8) : count > totalCircleSide ? distanceToTable + distanceX+smallCircleRadius:  controlX
    // let y = i < 2 ? table.y() - distanceToTable/2: count > totalCircleSide ? controlY : distanceToTable + distanceY*smallCircleRadius

    //let x = table.x()
    //let y = table.y()
    group.add(new Konva.Circle({ radius: smallCircleRadius, fill: '#d2d6df', stroke: '#c3c6cf',strokeWidth: 3, x, y }));
    
   
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself a simple model that describes the position of the circles in simple relationship of circles to the table.  Something like this can be extended via different models to accommodate other table layouts as the description of the layout is entirely in the model data.

```js
const
  // Set up a canvas stage
  containerEle = document.getElementById('container'),
  stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: "container",
    size: {
      width: containerEle.offsetWidth,
      height: containerEle.offsetHeight
    }
  }),

  layer = new Konva.Layer();

stage.add(layer);

const model = {
  table: {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 200,
    height: 400,
    fill: 'black',
    stroke: 'silver',
    strokeWidth: 5
  },
  seat: {
    radius: 40,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'silver',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    gap: 20
  },
  seats: [{
      name: "Seat 1",
      x: "25%",
      y: "-1r"
    },
    {
      name: "Seat 2",
      x: "75%",
      y: "-1r"
    },
    {
      name: "Seat 3",
      tableX: 1,
      tableY: 0,
      x: "1r",
      y: "16.6%"
    },
    {
      name: "Seat 4",
      tableX: 1,
      tableY: 0,
      x: "1r",
      y: "50%"
    },
    {
      name: "Seat 5",
      tableX: 1,
      tableY: 0,
      x: "1r",
      y: "83.3%"
    },
    {
      name: "Seat 6",
      tableX: 0,
      tableY: 1,
      x: "75%",
      y: "1r"
    },
    {
      name: "Seat 7",
      tableX: 0,
      tableY: 1,
      x: "25%",
      y: "1r"
    },
  ]
}

// make the table

const table = new Konva.Rect(model.table);

layer.add(table)

for (const seat of model.seats) {
  const seatShape = new Konva.Circle(model.seat);

  let tablePos = {
    x: seat.tableX && seat.tableX === 1 ? model.table.x + model.table.width : model.table.x,
    y: seat.tableY && seat.tableY === 1 ? model.table.y + model.table.height : model.table.y
  }

  let position = {
    x: tablePos.x + getPosComponent(seat.x, model.seat.radius, model.table.width, model.seat.gap),
    y: tablePos.y + getPosComponent(seat.y, model.seat.radius, model.table.height, model.seat.gap)
  } 
  seatShape.position(position)
  layer.add(seatShape);

}

function getPosComponent(val, radius, size, gap) {

  if (val.indexOf('r') > 0) {
    let num = parseInt(val),
      sign = Math.sign(num);
    return sign * ((Math.abs(num) * radius) + gap);
  } else if (val.indexOf('%') > 0) {
    let num = parseFloat(val),
      sign = Math.sign(num);
    return sign * (size * num / 100);
  }

  throw new Error("Unexpected val format " + val);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=UTF-8>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8/konva.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    #container {
      width: 800px;
      height: 600px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I generate circle positions with dynamic data? I didn't understand :/

Comment: I get that the question was specifically for the 8 seat table layout - I answered that . To confirm, the critical point is using a simple model to define the seat positions in relation to the table dimensions.   What I meant about the dynamic thing was that often when you have a requirement like this, when you provide a solution, it will become apparent that the specification is bigger. For example, what about 2-seat tables, 3 seaters, 20 seaters, etc. Using the example code I posted, you can define all those models. Then you can respond quickly when the customer asks for other table layouts.